# Mistakenly remove Docker container

Tags: docker, metricbeat

I mistakenly removed my docker metricbeat container and the status is dead now. I am trying to restart it but I get an error saying 
"Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container metricbeat: Container is marked for removal and cannot be started."

I would appreciate any help on how I can restart that container. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If it is still running, snapshot it with `docker commit` (or `docker commit --pause=false`, if it doesn't let you do it otherwise). Then, let it die and start a new one from the image that you saved with `commit`.

NOTE, I don't know for a fact that this will work (haven't tried it), but if all else fails - and if you have access to the host where the container is running, you can find out where the container's files are with `docker inspect` and grab the directory from the place where docker keeps all volume images (usually `/var/lib/docker`).